# How to fit a wide picture on two columns

Tags: floats, two-column

I am working in a two-column file and want to add a picture to the top or bottom of a page that stretches over both columns.

```
\pdfoutput=1    
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage[review]{acl}    
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
    
\title{This is my Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Architecture.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With this code, the image has the right width. However, it is located in the right column and therefore, half of the image is not captured in the document:

[image]

How can I show this picture over de width of the entire page (preferably, at the top of a page)?

Comment: have you tried with `\begin{figure*}...\end{figure*}`?

Comment: That works, thank you! If you make this an answer, then I will make it the accepted answer.

Comment: This is really a duplicate --- marked as such. Happy to have helped!